# getJSON is not working with cryptocompare api

Tags: jquery, json

Can anyone help me how to get data from the cryptocompare api?
I do not know what I'm wrong, but this code below does not work.
I'm using jquery-1.10.2 for this example.
The json from cryptocompare looks like this:

{
  "Response": "Error",
  "Message": "",
  "Type": 1,
  "Aggregated": false,
  "Data": [],
  "Path": "/data/",
  "ErrorsSummary": "Not implemented"
}

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/", {}, 

function(data) {
    console.log( "success : " + data);
}).fail(function(jqxhr, status, error) {
    console.log( "error :" + error );
}).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the `URL` of the `$.getJSON` , i remove the `https:` and it works , as per your requirement. if you don't write `https: or http:` then it is auto consider.

```js
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "//min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/", {}, 

function(data) {
    debugger;
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(jqxhr, status, error) {
    console.log( "error :" + error );
}).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this does not work on my page. Could there be anything wrong with my server? My page is http://reffey.nl/coints/coints.php

Comment: becuase you are calling , `https` from `http` server.

Comment: I updated my server to https and I sorry to say that it still doesn't work. Can you tell me if there is something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

But your json url is wrong.

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

And i tried one sample json.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG", {}, 

function(data) {
    console.log( "success : " +JSON.stringify(data) );
}).fail(function(jqxhr, status, error) {
    console.log( "error :" + error );
}).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whqLemmg/) Look console.